# I installed Eclipse IMP, eclipse ide can't open

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I installed [IMP](http://eclipse-imp.sourceforge.net/) project on eclipse, when i restart Eclipse, OPS.....

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000, pid=13303, tid=3020905360
#
# JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/DEVELOPMENT/eclipse-galileo-SR1/hs_err_pid13303.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted
```

---------------  S Y S T E M  DETAIL  ---------------

IDE: Eclipse Ganymede

OS:5.0

uname:Linux 2.6.28-17-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 1 18:57:07 UTC 2009 i686
libc:glibc 2.9 NPTL 2.9 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC infinity, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:1.28 1.18 1.14

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 2022412k(207344k free), swap 5919912k(5835804k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01) for linux-x86 JRE (1.6.0_16-b01), built on Jul 31 2009 06:19:30 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.1-7a (J2SE release)

time: Tue Dec  8 10:51:33 2009
elapsed time: 28 seconds

Comment: When i change workspace it was ok !, Bu i want to go back to working workspace.

Comment: I delete .metadata folder of eclipse workspace folder in my working workspace. Then everythings turned on. I can't understand anything. I think that it is another eclipse joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just .metadata crash of eclipse after installed **[Eclipse IMP](http://www.eclipse.org/imp/)**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure IMP is compatible with an eclipse Galileo (3.5).

Their [installation page](http://eclipse-imp.sourceforge.net/installing/index.html) mentions eclipse3.2

Comment: after .metadata deleted operation, everything is fine (i import all projects again). I have checked Eclipse installation details it seems IMP installed. 

  IMP Runtime (Incubation) 0.1.101 org.eclipse.imp.runtime.feature.group
  IMP Source Formatting Support (Incubation) 0.1.5 org.eclipse.imp.formatting.feature.group
  IMP Support for Java-Hosted Languages (Incubation) 0.1.1 org.eclipse.imp.java.hosted.feature.group

I think this installation operation broke workspace .metadata

Comment: Also i trust eclipse installer :) that didn't give any error when installation phase.